# How to access the first element of an array and click the same at runtime using selenium web driver?

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have a drop list as id="product-size" and the items S,M,L,XL.

```html
<select id="product-size" onchange=" addToWishList();">
 <option>Select</option>
 <option id="2119362" value="4">S</option>
 <option id="2119363" value="7">M</option>
 <option id="2119364" value="8">L</option>
 <option id="2119365" value="4">XL</option>
</select>
```

I have used an array to store these items and at Runtime I need to access the first element 'S'.The problem I am facing is ,I was not able to click on the first element S at runtime.
I have written the code as follows :

```java
driver.get("https://m.staging.karmaloop.com/product/The-Infinity-Tee/407819");
WebElement j =driver.findElement(By.id("product-size"));
String text = j.getText(); 
String[] DDLcount =text.split("\n");
for (int i=1;i<=DDLcount.length-1;i++)
    {       
    driver.findElement(By.xpath(Testconfiguration.size_dropdown_10deep)).click();
    Thread.sleep(5000);
    driver.findElement(By.name(DDLcount[i])).click(); 
    }
```

Can anyone help me to sort out this problem  ?

Comment: Did it throw an exception?

Comment: @John Yes It has thrown an Exception as org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: no such element

Comment: @John Yes It has thrown an Exception as org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: no such element –

Comment: @Baburaj Is there a specific reason for using an array? The same can be done using select class!! Let me know I can give the code for the same.

Comment: Can I know why do you want to click them ??

Comment: @Vinay .In that dropdown ,there is an option called 'Select'.But I dont want to click that ,instead I need to click on size, 'S','L''M','XL'.Can u provide a code to click on the size 'S' ?

Comment: @HarshavardhanKonakanchi .I am clicking that 's' because I need to know that size exists or not.

Comment: @Baburaj clicking on it will not tel you if the object is there is not. Instead get all the values from the drop down and verify if the value that has to be selected is present in the drop down or not? Do you want the code for that?

Comment: @Vinay Can U please provide the code for that please ??

Comment: @Vinay have a minor requirement .I have to validate whether a error message comes in the page while clicking on any size like "Product is Out of stock" .If the product is out of stock, I have to click on the next size available in the dropdown.Can u please help again :) ?

Comment: @BaburajV can you give me the url. Otherwise it will be difficult.

Comment: @Vinay https://m.staging.karmaloop.com/product/The-Infinity-Tee/407819

Comment: @BaburajV can you give me the scenario where this message will be displayed so that I can reproduce it.

Comment: @Vinay This will not happen every time because , only if the product is out of stock we can see this error message when we click on the ADD TO CART button. You just give me how could I compare whether that error message matches with the error message in the code and so that I will execute next size

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the code you've supplied, you're using an invalid selector for the Options.

They don't appear to have a `name` attribute

Aside from modifying the loop, you could make the operation faster if the DOM isnt reconstructed.

```
WebElement selectBox = driver.findElement(By.xpath(Testconfiguration.size_dropdown_10deep));
List<WebElement> options = selectBox.findElements(By.tagName("option"));
for ( WebElement option : options )
{      
    selectBox.click();
    option.click();
}
```

Comment: I have couple of questions regarding this :                                         1.When I copy the code you have provided , it shows error at' selectbox'.How can I resolve this ? 2.Can I get the first element in that dropdown ?

Comment: What error? And findElements populates the list in the order they're constructed in the DOM. So `options.get(0)` should be the first element in the dropdown

Comment: If you don't need any of the other options, you could even run `selectBox.findElement(By.tagName("option"));` or `driver.findElement(By.id("2119362"));` or `driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("option[value='4']"));`

Comment: I just want to know , what is this selectBox meant for ??When I pasted the code ,the red underline displayed below the selectBox and when I hover the mouse , it shows error as "selectBox cannot be resolved".

Comment: I am sorry ...it happened because the first line of code WebElement selectBox..was commented !!! Now it is working .Thanks  for you help.Thank u so much .Bye

Comment: I have a minor requirement .I have to validate whether a error message comes in the page while clicking on any size like "Product is Out of stock" .If the product is out of stock, I have to click on the next size available in the dropdown.Can u please help again :) ?

Comment: Sorry, had to sleep. And I would suggest using the Page Object pattern and implementing conditional actions.

Answer (score 0):

```
By locator = By.id("product-size");
Select select = new Select(webdriver.findElement(locator));
```

You can you use any of the three following options to select an item from dropdown

```
select.selectByIndex(index); // Give Index as parameter
select.selectByValue(value); // Give the value of the option tag 
select.selectByVisibleText(value); // Give the visible text as parameter
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 WebElement element =driver.findElement(By.id("product-size"));
Select sel = new Select(element);
List<WebElement> items = sel.getOptions();
boolean stringExits = false;
for(int i =0; i<items.size(); i++)
{
    String text = items.get(i).getText();
    if(text.equals("S"))
    {
         stringExists = true;
         break;
    }
}

if(stringExits)
{
     System.out.println("The string exists");
}else
{
     System.out.println("The string does not exist");
}
```

Comment: I have pasted the code but it shows some error in the statement.          Select sel = new Select(element)